# Python: if len(list) giving different results in different circumstances?

Tags: python, list, printing

I am trying to write a music program in Python that takes some music written by the user in a text file and turns it into a midi. I'm not particularly experienced with python at this stage so I'm not sure what the reason behind this issue is. I am trying to write the source file parser for the program and part of this process is to create a list containing all the lines of the text file and breaking each line down into its own list to make them easier to work with. I'm successfully able to do that, but there is a problem.

I want the code to **ignore** lines that are only whitespace (So the user can make their file at least kind of readable without having all the lines thrown together one on top of the other), but I can't seem to figure out how to do that. I tried doing this

```
with open(path, "r") as infile:
    for row in infile:
        if len(row):
            srclines.append(row.split())
```

And this **does** work as far as creating the list of lines and separating each word goes, BUT it still appends the empty lines that are only whitespace... I confirmed this by doing this

```
for entry in srclines:
    print entry
```

Which gives, for example

```
['This', 'is']
[]
['A', 'test']
```

With the original text being

```
This is

A test
```

But strangely, if during the printing stage I do another len() check then the empty lines are actually **ignored** like I want, and it looks like this

```
['This', 'is']
['A', 'test']
```

What is the cause of this? Does this mean I can only go over the list and remove empty entries after I generate It? Or am I just doing the line import code wrong? I am using python 3.6 to test this code with by the way

Comment: Please look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` contains a newline, so it's not empty. But `row.split()` doesn't find any non-whitespace characters, so it returns an empty list.

Use

```
if len(row.strip()):
```

to ignore the newline (and any other leading/trailing spaces).

Or more simply:

```
if row.strip():
```

since an empty string is falsy.

Comment: `if row.strip():` is enough - empty strings are falsy as well, no need to `len()` them

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a [list comprehension](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_list_comprehension.php):

```
with open('d.txt', "r") as infile:
    print([i.strip().split() for i in infile if i.strip()])
```

Output:

```
[['This', 'is'], ['A', 'test']]
```

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thanks for telling me, i will edit my answer

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Now my answer is still using a list comprehension, but it does not contain `None`'s  because i am not using those list functions that return `None`'s i.e append, reverse etc.

Comment: This is much better so, but there's still a problem: the OP wants to ignore lines that are only whitespace, and you'll get the same  empty lists he got if one of the lines is, for example, `'                     \n'`

Answer (score 0):

testdoc.txt has lot of empty lines; but in output they are out;

```
src = 'testdoc.txt'
with open(src, 'r') as f:
    for r in f:
        if len(r) > 1:
            print(r.strip())
```

and now you can obviously put this all in list or in list line by line instead of print whatever fits your further logic